# Android layer-list affecting position of floating action button

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, layer-list

I am creating an app where a layer-list is used as background and a floating action button is also used. When the layer-list is set as the background of the relative layout, it changes the position of the FAB, but I cannot understand why it happens.

I want the FAB to be positioned at the bottom left. When I don't have the background set as my layer-list, it appears where I have coded.

[image: FAB without background added to relative layout]

But when I add the background attribute to the Relative layout, FAB automatically moves in.

[image: FAB when background added to relative layout]

I can't understand what is affecting this behavior of FAB.

XML for layer_list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="64dp"
            android:left="32dp"
            android:right="32dp"
            android:top="64dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="64dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="64dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="64dp"
            android:topRightRadius="64dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

XML for Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/home_layer_list">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello world" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"/>
```

How can I make the FAB move back to the position where it was initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your layout like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home_layer_list">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In your layout : your main layout is relative layout and you gave background to it.Now in background file which is home_layer_list.xml,you used padding bottom,padding top,padding right and paading left.So your main relative layout wrap by padding .And floating action button is in your relative layout ,So floating button also take padding effect.